# How to sum nodes with XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

[Hi, I found this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518347/xsl-how-to-sum-elements-in-different-nodes) but isn't what I want. I want this output

Driver B 27

Driver A 18

This is the XML:

```
<grid>
    <driver>
        <name>Driver B</name>
        <points>
            <imola>10</imola>
            <monza>9</monza>
            <silverstone>8</silverstone>
        </points>
    </driver>
    <driver>
        <name>Driver A</name>
        <points>
            <imola>7</imola>
            <monza>6</monza>
            <silverstone>5</silverstone>
        </points>
    </driver>
</grid>
```

And this is the XSLT:

```
 <xsl:template match="/grid">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Championship</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Classification</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="driver" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="driver">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(???)" /> <!-- Here, I don't know the code to sum the points of the races-->

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm sure the solution is easy, but I can't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/grid">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Championship</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Classification</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="driver" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="driver">
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, ' ', sum(points/*))" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, `*` means "match any child element".

This produces the output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Championship</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Classification</h1>
    <p>Driver B 27</p>
    <p>Driver A 18</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! The * was the key, totally obvious now. Now I will try to make a table and show on order.

I think I cant vote because my reputation isn't enough, however, +1 for your answer.